# Identify if a user is logged in in a page in Dotnet nuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

In my dotnetnet Nuke project, I have to put a sentence in a page for signed (logged in) users. And I have to put another sentence for unsigned users. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the same code that's written in login skin object here:
https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/30bd1a1bd9d2962a36f6e39403f00ba5877dcfab/Website/admin/Skins/Login.ascx.cs#L84

`Visible = (!PortalSettings.HideLoginControl || Request.IsAuthenticated)                 && (!PortalSettings.InErrorPageRequest() || ShowInErrorPage);`

You can only use Request.IsAuthenticated in your case as well.

-- old answer --

Use [login skin object](http://www.thinkofdesign.com/resources/dotnetnuke-skinning-reference/#obj-login) provided by dnn to do so.